# Python: how to do this list comprehension with multiple nested lists?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm processing text that I need to break up into a list of sentence tokens, which are themselves broken down into word tokens.  For example:

```
raw_text = "the cat in the hat.  green eggs and ham.  one fish two fish."
```

I also have a list of stopwords that I want to remove from the text:

```
stopwords = ['the', 'and', 'in']
```

I'm doing the list comprehension using the nltk module:

```
from nlkt import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize

sentence_tokens = [word_tokenize(sentence) for sentence in sent_tokenize(raw_text)]
```

This yields the following:

```
[['the', 'cat', 'in', 'the', 'hat', '.'], ['green', 'eggs', 'and', 'ham', '.'], ['one', 'fish', 'two', 'fish', '.']]
```

I can filter out the stopwords with nested for loops:

```
for sentences in sentence_tokens:
    for word in sentences:
        if word in stop:
            sentences.remove(word)
```

What I'm having trouble doing is combining these all into a single list comprehension so it's a bit cleaner.  Any advice?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make  *stopword* a `set`, you can then use a *list comp* to filter out the words from each sublist that are in the set of stopwords:

```
stopwords = {'the', 'and', 'in'}


l = [['the', 'cat', 'in', 'the', 'hat', '.'], ['green', 'eggs', 'and', 'ham', '.'], ['one', 'fish', 'two', 'fish', '.']]


l[:] = [[word for word in sub if word not in stopwords] for sub in l]
```

Output:

```
[['cat', 'hat', '.'], ['green', 'eggs', 'ham', '.'], ['one', 'fish', 'two', 'fish', '.']]
```

Using `l[:]` means we will mutate the original object/list, if we broke it  up into a for loop:

```
# for each sublist in l
for sub in l:
    # for each word in the sublist, keep it only if it is not in stopwords 
    sub[:] =  [word for word in sub if word not in stopwords]
```

Your own code also has a bug, you should never iterate over and mutate a list by removing elements, you would need to make a copy or we could also use `reversed`:

```
for sentences in l:
    for word in reversed(sentences):
        if word in stopwords:
            sentences.remove(word)
```

When you remove an element starting from the left, you can end up removing the wrong elements as what a certain pointer was pointing to when the loop started may not be the same so on future removes you can remove the wrong element.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks a lot for the explanation, and also for pointing out the error in my previous code.  It's very much appreciated!  I'm pretty new to python and I probably wouldn't have figured that out!

Answer (score 0):

Tip: NLTK is not required for this task. A simple Python logic will do.
Here is the cleaner way to remove stop-words from text. I'm using Python 2.7 here.

When you want a string instead of list of words:

```
raw_text = "the cat in the hat.  green eggs and ham.  one fish two fish."
stopwords = ['the', 'and', 'in']
clean_text = " ".join(word for word in raw_text.split() if word not in stopwords)
```

When you want a list of words:

```
raw_text = "the cat in the hat.  green eggs and ham.  one fish two fish."
stopwords = ['the', 'and', 'in']
clean_list = [word for word in raw_text.split() if word not in stopwords]
```

Comment: OP has a nested list.